# Unresolved inclusion: <iostream> in eclipse on mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, compiler-construction, eclipse-indigo

Eclipse will not allow me to include `<iostream>`. I'm on a mac and when I try the same thing using xcode it works. I'm running eclipse Indigo and I've tried both the MAc OS X compiler option and the cross platform one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I resolved this by manually adding the path to iostream to my project:

Right click on project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Sympols -> GNU C++ (under Languages column in Includes) -> Add

I added the following (the ones in Bold) -- I think the second one is what you need:

[image: screenshot of my elcipse settings]

Comment: Adding just the path `/usr/include` here was enough for me, I believe there's no need to go digging into the actual SDK version folders.