# Cannot use include header files in Eclipse CDT Juno for Mac

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, osx-yosemite

I am using Eclipse Juno CDT in Mac OS - Yosemite and somehow I cannot use any header files other than the  iostream; despite the fact that all the header-files are included in the **includes** folder.

The main() program executes perfectly for "Hello World" under iostream, which I guess resides in the same location (inside **includes**); but throws error for other header file.

Can someone tell me how to point my main() program to the includes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by right-clicking my C project and adding the path `/usr/include` to the includes under `Properties`->`C/C++ General`->`Paths and Sybmols`->`Includes`->`GNU C`->Add...

Why it's necessary to perform this step when the project "Includes" suggeste Eclipse already knows the include path is not clear to me either, but I had the exact same issue, and was able to resolve it this way.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543198/unresolved-inclusion-iostream-in-eclipse-on-mac) for a picture of the dialog.